# How do you allow the user to input negative numbers into an array and change starting index?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

I recently made an application that reads a number of integers that are in the range of 0 to 50 and counts how many times each one is entered. I also made it so that it counts the number of times each integer was entered. Now, I have to change the range from 0 to 50 to -25 to 25. However, When I input negative numbers, I get an Out of Bound error.

I have been experimenting with the array declarations sand I just need to know what I need to do in order to change the range. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SixTwo
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int[] nums = new int[51];

        int[]occur = {-25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10,
        -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
        int[] nums = {-25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10,
        -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
        System.out.println("Enter an integer (00 to quit)");
        int integer = sc.nextInt();
        //for(int index = 0; index <= integer; index++ ){
        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(n > 25){
                continue;
            }
            if(n == 00){
                break;
            }
            occur[n] += 1;
            nums[n] = n;
        }

        System.out.println("All Numbers entered:");
        for(int i = -25; i < nums.length; i++){
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
        for(int i = -25; i < occur.length; i++){
            System.out.print(occur[i] + "  ");
        }
        sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: In Java, you can't.  Basically you're going to have to fake it.  If your index `i` goes from -25 to 25, the just add 25 to `i` to bring the first index up to 0, and the rest will increment naturally from there.

Comment: @markspace I think its possible because one of my java assignments says to do so.

Comment: Have you added the logic in this questions it's just taking input and printing two arrays ? Does this initialization of occur array contain correct data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use an array to do your task, then you may need to change the logic as show in below. I have added the inline comments to describe the logic.

First of all you need to change the initialization of occur array as below which will initialize all the occurrences to zero when application start.

```
    int[] occur = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0 };
```

Then you need to take the in put as String otherwise you will not be able to identify whether the user enter 00 to exit from program. After that validation String can be convert to int using `Integer.valueOf(input)`.

Then you may need to check whether the input is out of range by `n > 25 || n<-25`. If it's out of range error message will print and again ask user to enter valid number.

Then you need to change the for loop initial parameters from 0 to occur length. You cant use minus values for indexes in array. I believe you will be able to understand other logic in the code.

You can go through the updated code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SixTwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // int[] nums = new int[51];


    //You need to change the initial data of the occur array to zero
    int[] occur = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0 };

    int[] nums = { -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6,
            -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
            23, 24, 25 };

    for (;;) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer between -25 to 25 (00 to quit)");
        //You need to take input as String other wise you will not be able to find whether user enter 00
        String input = sc.next();
        if(input.equals("00")){
            break;
        }

        int n = 0;

        try {
            n=Integer.valueOf(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }

        //You need to add check whether entered number out of range 
        if (n > 25 || n<-25) {
            System.out.println("Out of range");
            continue;
        }

        occur[25+n] = occur[25+n]+1;
    }

    System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(nums[i] + ":"+occur[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    sc.close();
}
}
```

Then lets assume if you got in put as 1,3,4,4,-25,0,0,00

```
All Occurrences: 
-25:1
-24:0
-23:0
-22:0
-21:0
-20:0
-19:0
-18:0
-17:0
-16:0
-15:0
-14:0
-13:0
-12:0
-11:0
-10:0
-9:0
-8:0
-7:0
-6:0
-5:0
-4:0
-3:0
-2:0
-1:0
0:2
1:1
2:0
3:1
4:2
5:0
6:0
7:0
8:0
9:0
10:0
11:0
12:0
13:0
14:0
15:0
16:0
17:0
18:0
19:0
20:0
21:0
22:0
23:0
24:0
25:0
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I get your code, however, I never learned this part:  `try {
            n=Integer.valueOf(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }`                                                                                                                              will you please explain what `try`,  `catch`, and `Exception` does? I never heard of those.

Comment: Its added due to the fact that user can add non integer value and in that case it should be handle in the code. So if the user added non integer value application will again ask to enter input again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a number at negative index. Try `nums[n + 25]` for counting occurences.
Also iterating from -25 to `occur.length` doesn't make sense since you only have 50 numbers and the `occur.length` is 50 (so it would mean that the arrays length is 75. You should start at  0.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array? Just use a map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
```

Then for each number input:

```
int n; // input by user
counts.merge(n, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

After all inputs you'll have the counts of each number, which you output like this:

```
counts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that this will work for *any* integer values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is quite simple: Java only allows positive integers and 0 as array indeces and you can't change that. YOu can however use a `Map` instead of an array. A map is basically an array, but the index can be anything, e. g. a `String` or negative integers, really anything.

Here's the ready-to-use code that utilizes a Map. I also took the liberty to clean your source code a little and added some tips that will be wuite helpful for you, I guess:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SixTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<Integer, Integer> occur = new HashMap<>();

        // initialize the map with zeros
        for (int i = -25; i <= 25; i++) {
            occur.put(i, 0);
        }

        for (; ; ) {
            // Java does not differentiate between the integers 00 and 0 so better use anything else that is not a
            // valid value, like the word 'quit'
            System.out.println("Enter an integer (Enter quit to quit)");
            // We need to read the input as a String now to recognize the word quit
            String input = sc.nextLine();

            // input=="quit" wouldn't work because Strings are not a primitive datatype
            if (input.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            // Now convert the input to int
            int n = Integer.parseInt(input);

            // Don't forget to check against -25 too
            if (n > 25 || n < -25) {
                System.out.println("Number was out of range, ignoring...");
                continue;
            }
            occur.put(n, occur.get(n) + 1);
        }

        System.out.println("All Numbers entered:");
        for (int i = -25; i <= 25; i++) {
            // print the right number of spaces to get a perfect table
            for (int spc = 4 - Integer.toString(i).length(); spc > 0; spc--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
        for (Map.Entry entry : occur.entrySet()) {
            // print the right number of spaces to get a perfect table
            for (int spc = 4 - entry.getValue().toString().length(); spc > 0; spc--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print(entry.getValue());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```